# Set ls to return colored results by default

Tags: linux, bash, .bash-profile

In my .bashrc I have the following lines to turn on colors for grep and ls

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
```

I've tried changing the alias to `export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'` but that doesn't work.
Is there anyway to use an export instead of alias. And are there actually any benefits to one way over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like `LS_OPTIONS` is more a Operating System startup configuration in some Linux/UNIX systems. `ls` won't read that variable, so it seems that the only viable option is the `alias` thing.

You can combine things to do what you want, though. For instance, just define `ls` as an alias like this:

```
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

and then changing `LS_OPTIONS` will actually take effect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the Gnu `grep` command, the Gnu version of the `ls` command doesn't examine the environment variable `LS_OPTIONS`. Setting it doesn't do you any good unless you alias the `ls` command itself to use it:

```
$ alias ls="ls \$LS_OPTIONS"
$ ls      #Doesn't display color
$ export LS_OPTIONS="--color=auto"
$ ls      #Displays directory in color
$ unset LS_OPTIONS
$ ls      #Back to old behavior
```